# how to know if type is a class _ctypes.PyCArrayType?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I am trying to call some c APIs from python.
I have a class defined like

```
class X(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("member", ctypes.c_int * 5)
    ]
```

I wanted to know if member is of an array type. In order to do that I did following experiments but I can not check if type of a is an array.

```
>>>
>>> import ctypes
>>> a = 5*ctypes.c_int
>>> type(a)
<class '_ctypes.PyCArrayType'>
>>> b = (type(a) == _ctypes.PyCArrayType)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'ctypes' has no attribute 'PyCArrayType'
>>>
```

How can I check if type of a is an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [[Python.Docs]: class ctypes.Array(*args)](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Array) (**emphasis** is mine):

> **Abstract base class for arrays**.

Translated to code:

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes as cts
> >>>
> >>> I5 = cts.c_int * 5
> >>> I5.__mro__
> (<class '__main__.c_long_Array_5'>, <class '_ctypes.Array'>, <class '_ctypes._CData'>, <class 'object'>)
> >>> issubclass(I5, cts.Array)
> True
> >>>
> >>> i5 = I5()
> >>> isinstance(i5, cts.Array)
> True
> ```